# using CiviCRM like Access?

Tags: contacts, custom-fields, fields, display, data-model

I am new to CiviCRM. Is it possible for me to use CiviCRM like MS Access?

I really don't need all the fields CiviCRM is offering.

All I need is the fields shown as below:

First Name
Last Name
State
License Number
Expiration Date

How can I ditch all other info and just come up with those 5 fields for Contacts? I also don't want the interface to display anything other than those 5 fields I am going to be entering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, CiviCRM has a high learning curve, so if you think it's overkill for your needs, I'd advise you to consider whether this solution is right for you at this time.

If CiviCRM generally meets your needs and you're just looking for a way to simplify data entry, you might have a look at the [Profiles](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/profiles/) chapter in the user guide.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I believe that is the right direction for me to go. Now, I have more questions if you have time. After I come up with the profile structure like mentioned above, can I create another group of profile, and compare those two groups for returning any matching or unmatching profile data?

Comment: @ChrisP777 Your follow-up question isn't clear.  Also, the Q&A nature of Stack Exchange means that almost no one will see your follow-up question when posted as a comment.  Please post it as a new question and it will get more attention!

Answer (score 1):

For such a simple requirement some people would consider using a Google spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

I will have to agree with GinkgoFJG. CiviCRM really does have a high learning curve and if you really only need those 5 fields, you might be better building this form in Drupal or Wordpress. Personally, I recommend Drupal because you'll be able to do a lot more displaying of fields in Views (and if you like, integrate your expiration field in another table or calendar, set permissions by field type).

If you use CiviCRM for your purpose, its definitely possible. You would use Profiles. On the backend though, you'll just see all the fields CiviCRM provides, some you won't be able to remove from the interface (e.g., employer, job title, etc). If you think your setup/fields in the future then CiviCRM will be powerful for you to expand your needs.